# Spark sql- How to interact with data frames which were generated by sqlcontext with hglcontext?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two files emp1 and emp2.

```
emp1:
101,aaa,30000,m,11   
102,bbbb,40000,f,12  
103,cc,60000,m,12  
104,dd,80000,f,11                 
105,cccc,90000,m,12  

emp2:
201,dk,90000,m,11  
202,mm,100000,f,12  
203,mmmx,80000,m,12  
204,vbvb,70000,f,11
```

After that i have created a case class to provide schema to emp1 and emp2.

```scala
case class Emp(id:Int, name:String, 
               sal:Int, sex:String, dno:Int)
```

then i have define a function toEmp:

```scala
def toEmp(x:String) = {  
  val  w = x.split(",")  
  Emp(w(0).toInt,   
  w(1), w(2).toInt,  
  w(3), w(4).toInt)  
} 

val e1 = emp1.map(x => toEmp(x))  
val e2 = emp2.map(x => toEmp(x))  
val df1 = e1.toDF  
val df2 = e2.toDF


df1.registerTempTable("df1")
df2.registerTempTable("df2")

val df = sqlContext.sql("select * from 
               df1 union all  select * from df2")

df.registerTempTable("df")

val res = HiveContext.sql("select sex,sum(sal) as tot, count(*) as cnt 
                                                  from df group by sex")
```

Here i am getting error. can anyone help me how to interact with data frames which were generated by sqlContext by using HiveContext?

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto Does it matter? It cannot work in any version...

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto Unlikely, unless `HiveContext` is an alias for `sqlContext` which is the one which has been used to import implicits in the current scope. Remember that we table is restricted to specific context.

Comment: Yes @zero323 as usual you are right, however I don't see anything uncommon in Naveen's query that can't be executed in his sqlContext.

Comment: Another possible problem (on top of the one described above) is that `HiveContext` is actually a companion object not an instance. And it simply doesn't have `sql` method.